# Export to Excel/PDF from LINQ in MVC

Tags: linq, asp.net-mvc-4, export-to-excel

I need to export a set of data to **Excel/PDF** which i am retrieving in **LINQ** in **ASP.NET MVC4** application in a button click. I am not using any Grid in the webpage. Which is the simple and best way to export the data?